# I can't browse the network from Nautilus

Tags: networking, nautilus, unity-dash, sharing

It's [Ubuntu 14.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29) LTS (Trusty Tahr). Long story short, I uninstalled a lot of software by mistake. Among others I uninstalled Unity, Samba...even Nautilus, then switched to tty1 and installed all that I could think of, all thet I needed so far. The only thing that does not work is browsing the network from Nautilus or from Dash. Samba works, smbtree gives all networks, smbclient can access a Windows share and I even copied some folders from a Windows server, but when I try from Dash it says:

> This location could not be displayed.
>
> Sorry, could not display all the contents of “server (smb)”: The specified location is not supported

It was nice accessing Windows shares from Dash and if you would help me I'd like to get it back :)

Comment: Do you `gvfs-backends` package installed?

Comment: yes thats it thanks. all gvfs was installed except gvfs-backends :)

Answer (score 13):

Installing `gvfs-backends` should allow Nautilus to use most common protocols (including SMB, SSH, etc.).

```
sudo apt-get install gvfs-backends
```