# Can a Network Share tab be added to Nemo in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, nautilus, samba, 16.04, nemo

Recently, I had had an issue which required making a folder shareable on my local LAN. I noticed that under Ubuntu 16.04 there was no "*share*" tab in Nemo for making a folder shareable on the local LAN.

I also took a look at my other computer which is running Ubuntu 14.04. In that computer folders accessed with Nemo have a "*share*" tab. So it seems that the upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 "*removed*" the share "*tab*" for Nemo.

I am using Nemo as the file manager rather than Nautilus under Ubuntu 16.04. Nautilus is still available with the "*share*" tab.  However, utilizing Nemo as the principle file manager seems to have created an occasional situation where my computer under Ubuntu 16.04 is sometimes not recognized by the local LAN. Is there a way to add the "*share*" tab (enable sharing) in Nemo under Ubuntu 16.04 which should resolve the occasional concern of the computer not showing-up on the local LAN. (Evidently Nemo "*covers*" Nautilus, herby "*hiding*" the folder's share property.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/nemo
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nemo nemo-fileroller
```

`sudo apt-get install nemo-share
    then`reboot`.

Comment: My apologies. I failed to mention that I had previously tried that.

Comment: I had received the error message: "E: Unable to locate package nemo-share". I assumed that "nemo-share" package was made unavailable under Ubuntu 16.04 since you can get nemo by itself.

Comment: @Steve R. Answer edited to install latest nemo from webupd8

Comment: Didn't work. Your instructions worked up till "nemo-share". Still received the same error message that nemo-share package was unavailable. nemo-share did not show-up with synaptic either. Also, the folders on my desktop, once again, duplicated themselves, which appears to be a known issue. I had previously solved the duplicate folder issue by uninstalling nemo and reinstalling nemo.  The lack of a network share issue with nemo may eventually be resolved through a future Ubuntu upgrade. I'll stick with nautilus for now. Would be nice if Ubuntu would adopt nemo instead. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: I know nemo-share is in the repository as i installed it on the day i wrote my answer. Something in your configuration is preventing it being installed. Please repeat the three commands and paste the entire dialog into paste.ubuntu.com and edit your question to include a link to it.

Comment: **Success**. It worked this time, a mystery, but it worked!. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Had to do a reinstall. Needed `gvfs-backends` to be reinstalled. `sudo apt-get install gvfs-backends`. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/654687/i-cant-browse-the-network-from-nautilus